# Applying function to both sides of asymptotic expression

Tags: asymptotics

I apologize in advance if this has been asked elsewhere, but I couldn't find it.  This seems like it should be a pretty simple question, but I'm drawing a blank.

If you know that $f(x) \sim g(x)$, then under what conditions can you show that $F(f(x)) \sim F(g(x))$?

(This is not homework; just for personal interest.)

Comment: Being uniformly continuous is not enough: consider $f(n)=\pi n$ and $g(n)=\pi n+\pi/2$, hence $f\sim g$, but if we consider $F(n)=\sin(n)$, we conclude $F(f)\nsim F(g)$.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the line of thought that made me ask the question.  Maybe monotonicity gets around those issues?

Comment: Wait, that makes no sense.  Ignore my last comment.